# Can't use custom ruleset in maven-pmd-plugin 5.0.2

Tags: maven, customization, maven-plugin, pmd

I want maven-pmd-plugin to include rulesets that I specify and exclude some rules (specifically, UselessParentheses)

Just like described in [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/usingRuleSets.html), I placed the following in pmd.xml that is parent for all modules:

```xml
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <rulesets>
            <ruleset>/home/ubuntu/ruleset.xml</ruleset>
          </rulesets>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
```

and prepared a custom ruleset like with this:

```xml
  <!-- We'll use the entire rulesets -->
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/basic.xml"/>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/imports.xml"/>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/codesize.xml"/>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml"/>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/strings.xml"/>
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml"/>

  <!-- We want everything from this except some -->
  <rule ref="rulesets/java/unnecessary.xml">
    <exclude name="UselessParentheses"/>
  </rule>
```

as a main part.

Nevertheless, when I run `mvn clean jxr:jxr pmd:check` I have the "UselessParentheses" in reports. Moreover, running it with `-X` shows

```
[DEBUG] Preparing ruleset: java-basic
[DEBUG] Before: java-basic After: java-basic.xml
[DEBUG] The resource 'rulesets/java/basic.xml' was found as jar:file:/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/pmd/pmd/5.0.2/pmd-5.0.2.jar!/rulesets/java/basic.xml.
[DEBUG] Preparing ruleset: java-unusedcode
[DEBUG] Before: java-unusedcode After: java-unusedcode.xml
[DEBUG] The resource 'rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml' was found as jar:file:/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/pmd/pmd/5.0.2/pmd-5.0.2.jar!/rulesets/java/unusedcode.xml.
[DEBUG] Preparing ruleset: java-imports
[DEBUG] Before: java-imports After: java-imports.xml
[DEBUG] The resource 'rulesets/java/imports.xml' was found as jar:file:/home/ubuntu/.m2/repository/net/sourceforge/pmd/pmd/5.0.2/pmd-5.0.2.jar!/rulesets/java/imports.xml.
```

So it looks like pmd ignored my custom ruleset.

I want custom ruleset to work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've configured the ***maven-pmd-plugin*** as a [reporting](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Reporting) which is

> Reporting contains the elements that correspond specifically for ***the site generation phase***. Certain Maven plugins can generate reports defined and configured under the reporting element.

This means you should execute with the following command:-

```
mvn clean site
```

If you would like to execute as you mention, please copy your configure to [builds](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Build), e.g.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <rulesets>
                    <ruleset>/home/ubuntu/ruleset.xml</ruleset>
                </rulesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then when you execute the

```
mvn clean jxr:jxr pmd:check
```

The result should be as your expected. You can find further about Maven Pom, [here](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html).

I hope this may help.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.

Comment: Thank you. It works. I just did everything that they say in [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/usingRuleSets.html) and didn't get the results. There was not a single word about placing configuration in "build" section.

Comment: But if you look to http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/usage.html you see all places where you can put plug-in declaration...

Comment: As with many maven plugins, the documentation is lacking in detail.  I find this perplexing, considering it's what maven is supposed to be all about.