# Maven Site / Project Info Reports Plugins Produce Empty Dependency Report

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

A dependencies report generated using the maven-project-info-reports-plugin is erroneously  reporting only one project and zero transitive dependencies. However, a dependency-convergence report produces a complete list of dependencies. When running the project-info-reports:dependencies goal from the command line, either no output is being generated or the outputDirectory parameter is not working correctly (no report file is generated in the specified outputDirectory). Is there a default directory? I have only been able to produce the report with the mvn site plugin.

The only noticeable error I am getting is a series of "Artifact: XXXX has no file" errors, as reported in [MPIR-251](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MPIR-251), but I'm wondering if this is a red herring and not indicative of the cause of the problem. Thoughts?

Configuration:
maven: 3.0.3
maven-site-plugin:3.1
maven-project-info-reports-plugin: 2.6
OS: Mac OS-X

Answer (score 1):

As mentions at the [usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-project-info-reports-plugin/usage.html) page as

Maven has been configured to create the project info reports by default. There's no need to configure anything in your pom.xml to generate the project information reports.

Simply running

```
mvn site
```

If you would not to execute the *site*, please copy the *maven-project-info-reports-plugin* to the [build](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Build). Please see the detail at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133822/cant-use-custom-ruleset-in-maven-pmd-plugin-5-0-2/15153145#15153145). You may able to execute

```
mvn project-info-reports:dependencies
```

and you may see the result as your expected.

I hope this may help.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.

Comment: I tried both suggestions, but I still get the same results. The project-info-reports:dependencies command doesn't seem to honor the outputDirectory parameter and running the mvn site plugin generates an erroneous dependencies list that contains only one dependency. The mvn dependency plugin generates a complete list.

Comment: Are they the multiple modules? If you are looking at the report of the root/parent project, there will not be any report. You may need to drill down to each sub module report instead.

Comment: To collect all sites for multiple modules. After executing the `mvn site`, please execute the `mvn site:stage` at the root/parent project.

Comment: Yes, it is a multi-module project. I'm executing mvn site:run and accessing the report through a web browser.

Comment: It's quite strange. I'm trying to use `mvn site:run` at both my parent and child projects which define some dependencies. During navigating through web browser, the dependency report displays the correct list. Only different is I'm using Maven Site Plugin version 3.2

Comment: Quite strange indeed. I tried 3.2 as well... doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Does this work? I tried but it wrote only BUILD SUCCESS and nothing more.