# cobertura-maven-plugin excludes configuration

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, cobertura

I have a Maven project with a test case `DefaultViewTypeToFragmentMapperTest.java` in the directory `/src/test/java/test/com/mycompany/myproduct/android/viewtype2fragmentmapper/`.

I want this test case to be excluded from unit test coverage calculation. In order to achieve this result, I configured the plugin like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <formats>
            <format>html</format>
            <format>xml</format>
        </formats>
        <instrumentation>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>test/co/**/*.class</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </instrumentation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But I still see the aforementioned class in the coverage report.

How can I fix it such that the test case does not appear in the report and its coverage (0 % according to the report) is not taken into account?

Comment: Have you configured the cobertura-maven-plugin as a part of reporting or build? If you configured as reporting, please use the `mvn site`. If you would like to execute `mvn cobertura:cobertura`, please configured as a build. Please see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133822/cant-use-custom-ruleset-in-maven-pmd-plugin-5-0-2/15153145#15153145 for further information.

Comment: I configured it as part of the `<reporting>` node and I use only in scope of `mvn site`.

Comment: I found out, that the plugin has a helpful debug logging. Enable it with `mvn cobertura:... -X`

Answer (score 11):

After a lot try and fail I got it working.

1. Edit the pom.
2. mvn clean test-compile
3. mvn cobertura:cobertura
4. Reopen the page from Firefox. (make sure the page is not cached)

I got it working with:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
            <instrumentation>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>aaa/**/*.class</exclude>
                    <exclude>com/test/bbb/**/*.class</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </instrumentation>
        </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Change 'aaa' with the beginning of the package name to be excluded.
Change 'bbb' with your package name that you want to exclude from the report.

I hope it helps, 
Marc Andreu

Answer (score 6):

You should use the `<ignore>` tag.

```
<configuration>
  <instrumentation>
    <ignores>
      <ignore>com.example.boringcode.*</ignore>
    </ignores>
  </instrumentation>
</configuration>
```

`<exclude>` used within `<instrumentation>` simply excludes the package from what your instrumenting. Which in this case, is nothing because you're not doing anything.

Please see the [Mojo Maven Cobertura Plugin docs here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/cobertura-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Comment: Okay, let's go back to your exclude statement. What is test/co/**/*.class to you? The test your attempting to exclude is not inside of this package structure.

Comment: The documentation doesn't really explain the difference between `exclude` or `ignore`.

Answer (score 5):

Is it a typo?

`<exclude>test/co/**/*.class</exclude>`.

The **co** should be **com**.

BTW, `<ignores>` instructs Cobertura to ignore any calls to any method that matches the ignore regular expression. It will **NOT** skip over these classes during instrumention. To exclude classes from being instrumented, `<excludes>` should be used.

Comment: No, it's not. `The test.co.mycompany.*` package name is correct.

Comment: Well your folder name does not match that package name. You need to put "com"

Your post says code is in "/src/test/java/test/com/mycompany/myproduct/android"

Answer (score 4):

You should not append the .class as the following example

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <formats>
            <format>html</format>
            <format>xml</format>
        </formats>
        <instrumentation>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>test/co/**/*</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </instrumentation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

I hope this may help.

Answer (score 3):

I just lost two hours of my life getting an exclusion for Cobertura to be excluded, but finally succeeded.

The solution I found is that the plugin configuration with instrumentation & exclusion for the cobertura-maven-plugin MUST be in the build/plugins or build/pluginManagement chapter of the pom, while there **also** must be a reference to the cobertura-maven-plugin in the reporting chapter.

The pitfall here is that you initially start with defining the plugin at the reporting chapter, otherwise no report is generated. But the instrumentation itself doesn't pick up any configuration from that part of the pom. You need to define that within the build chapter.

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <instrumentation>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>my/exclusion/package/**</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </instrumentation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<reporting>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</reporting>
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [BertKoor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6381983/bertkoor)'s answer, I'd like to point out that if you're executing `mvn cobertura:cobertura` or `mvn cobertura:cobertura-integration-test` directly, your report will **still** include coverage on all instrumented classes found in your target directory, as reported [here](https://github.com/mojohaus/cobertura-maven-plugin/issues/20)!

If this is the case, make sure you do `mvn **clean** cobertura:cobertura` in order to clean up the target dir from a previous build first, **and then** instrument and run your tests.