# Organization of tested code and test cases in mavenized Android projects

Tags: android, maven, maven-3, emma

I have an Android application, which is built by Maven and now I want to measure unit test coverage. I tried Cobertura, but there was a [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15234914/cobertura-maven-plugin-excludes-configuration), which I couldn't fix.

Therefore, I want to switch to Emma.

I started to [read](https://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/EmmaMaven) about it and it appears to me that in order to use Emma it is necessary to separate the code of my application from the test cases (create separate Maven projects for the application and for its unit tests), i. e. have 2 different Maven projects.

Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

How about just separating src/main/java and src/test/java ? Although I'm not expert on Emma.

Comment: This is how the code is separated now (the usual Maven convention). The question is - can I run Emma with this code organization?