# which rulesets does the maven pmd plugin use by default?

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, pmd

I'm trying to figure out which rulesets the maven pmd plugin (I have version 3.4) uses by default.

According to the [plugin website](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/examples/usingRuleSets.html), it uses only basic.xml, unusedcode.xml and imports.xml. However, I can say for sure that it must also use unnecessary.xml and empty.xml (as we have failures in our code from those categories without changing the rules).

How do I figure out which other rulesets it's actually using by default?

I want to use the default rulesets, but I need to make a few minor adjustments, e.g. to the UselessParentheses rule [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15133822/cant-use-custom-ruleset-in-maven-pmd-plugin-5-0-2).

Other useful links:

- All java rulesets @ [github](https://github.com/pmd/pmd/tree/master/pmd-java/src/main/resources/rulesets/java)
- One [xml file that includes all java rules](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/net.sourceforge.pmd/pmd/5.0.1/rulesets/internal/all-java.xml) (somehow can't find find it on github)

Comment: Try running Maven with -X and look at the plugin config in the logs.  That might tell you what rule files are being used.

Comment: Tried that, didn't help. :( Also tried running the plugin with <verbose>true</verbose> and no luck there either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation of rulesets tag](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/pmd-mojo.html#rulesets) you are right:

> Defaults to the java-basic, java-empty, java-imports, java-unnecessary and java-unusedcode rulesets